# RabbitMQ cluster_partition_handling "pause_minority" unrecognised

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm having a weird issue with my RabbitMQ cluster. I'm running a 3-node cluster with RabbitMQ 3.6.5 on all of them. When I simulate a connection loss from one of the nodes ("I pull the cable from the back"), I see in the log files that a network partition took place. However, it then says:

`cluster_partition_handling "pause_minority" unrecognised, assuming 'ignore'`

Initially, I had the setting to "pause-minority" instead of pause_minority how it says in the documentation. However, changing it didn't help. I tried different variations and looked around for examples but couldn't find anything.

`{cluster_partition_handling, pause_minority},`

`{cluster_partition_handling, "pause_minority"},`

`{cluster_partition_handling,pause_minority},`

None of these worked. and I kept getting the same error.

If I restart the node however, it will work fine. The queue gets a new master, and when the node comes back, it syncs up with the others.

Why doesn't RabbitMQ recognize my setting and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you upload your config file ? this `{cluster_partition_handling, pause_minority}` should work. Maybe there is some other problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fixed my issue and it had more to do with me not seeing the bigger picture.

The reason why it was not working the first time was because I had the config file set up to use the line `{cluster_partition_handling, "pause-minority"}`. I had this setting on all 3 nodes and it was not correct. The proper argument according to documentation is `{cluster_partition_handling, pause_minority}`. While I did repair this mistake on one or two of the nodes, the third still had a wrong setting. Couple that with the fact that I was not fully aware that each node was applying the config file that is locally set, or that they do not use a joint file from the master node and I had this issue.

If anyone has this issue make sure that you know the settings of each node and how it plays out with other nodes, since each node can have a different setting than the rest.